# How can i set flag in a sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

My query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Basic
AS
SELECT id FROM my_post
UNION
SELECT id FROM scrap_post
```

If the row is from `my_post` then I want to set the flag `p`, otherwise `s`.

Comment: Don't use `UNION` unless you want to incur the performance overhead of removing duplicate values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a hard-coded value

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Basic
AS
select id,'p' as flag from my_post
UNION 
select id,'s' from scrap_post
```

**Note :** If you don't care about duplicates in result then change `UNION` to `UNION ALL` which runs faster